# Display current language Code - OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I have to use following code for display current language code. So, It is working fine in older version. but, it is not work in latest OpenCart version.

Code:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['language']; ?>
```

I got error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: language in
>   C:\xampplite\htdocs\2.2.0.0\catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\header.tpl
>   on line 58

Comment: If you want to display language code in opencart than you can used `<?php echo $lang; ?>` in your header file.

Comment: I have already try this. but, it is not work. actually, I have use is code in jquery code. $(document).ready(function() { $("#filter_name").autocomplete("getdata.php?lan=<?php echo $_SESSION['language']; ?>", { width: 260 }); });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do

```
<?php echo $lang; ?>
```

inside your `header.tpl`.

**OR**

In the `common/header.php` controller, there is a line.

```
$data['lang'] = $this->language->get('code');
```

You can echo it to get the language code.

Comment: I have already try this. but, it is not work. actually, I have use is code in jquery code. `$(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#filter_name").autocomplete("getdata.php?lan=<?php echo $_SESSION['language']; ?>", {
            width: 260
        });
    });`

Comment: I was already use this. but, it was not work. I don't know why.  but, it is working now. Thanks.

Comment: No problem @HarnishDesign